# How to submit form in a web page using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m doing my homework. I have built  a local web service.what should I do for submitting form with python?

I want to log in my local web service with python and a data dictionary.

Here is my local Web verification：

```py
def signin():
    if request.form['username']=='root' and request.form['password']=='1234':
        return '<h2>Login successfully</h2>'
    return '<h2>Login failed</h2>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using python3 you can use 'mechanicalsoup' library for this.
Have a look at to this example.Hope it will be helpful.

```
import mechanicalsoup  #importing the library

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("http://example.com/")

browser.select_form('form[action="/post"]') #selecting the form.
browser["name"] = "Name"
browser["email"] = "example@mail.com" #filling the fields in the form.

response = browser.submit_selected()
```